# How can i get table data using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to get table data from this [URL](https://www.larmtjanst.se/Efterlysta-objekt/Personbil/?s=True) but it's post method and I'm trying to implement the scrapy code but I'm facing 500 Error. But If you can check over Network section it's showing 200 but I'm getting 500 during scrapy time. Please check my code and let me know what's wrong i"M doing over here. Pelase help. Thank you. One more thing, user-agent already applied as well.

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser


class LarmSpider(Spider):
    name = 'larm'
    allowed_domains = ['larmtjanst.se']
    start_urls = ['https://www.larmtjanst.se/Efterlysta-objekt/Personbil/?s=True']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield FormRequest('https://www.larmtjanst.se/StolenItemsHelper/SearchAjax?category=Personbil',
                          formdata={'category': 'Personbil'},
                          callback=self.parse_form)

    def parse_form(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
        table = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "searchResultTable")]')[1]
        trs = table.xpath('.//tr')
        for tr in trs:
            reg_num = tr.xpath('.//td/a/text()').extract_first()

            yield {
                'Register Number': reg_num
            }
```

Output

> 2020-10-28 16:15:50 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave
> up retrying <POST
> https://www.larmtjanst.se/StolenItemsHelper/SearchAjax
> ?category=Personbil> (failed 3 times): 500 Internal Server Error
> 2020-10-28 16:15:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (500) <POST
> https://www.larmtjanst.se/StolenItemsHelper/SearchAjax?category=Personbil
>
> > (referer: https://www.larmtjanst.se/Efterlysta-objekt/Personbil/?s=True)
> > 2020-10-28 16:15:50 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO:
> > Ignoring response <500
> > https://www.larmtjanst.se/StolenItemsHelper/SearchAjax?
> > category=Personbil>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed

Comment: It seems that the table is dynamically loaded via javascript (client side), so I guess that data isn't valid for scraping when the spider runs, I would suggest integrating splash or selenium to preload the client side script that is generating the table then run your spider, this link might help [link](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not only provide the form data but also set some headers in order to get desired output. Feel free to use https://michael-shub.github.io/curl2scrapy/ to debug requests in scrapy shell. This one works for me:

```
from scrapy import Request

url = 'https://www.larmtjanst.se/StolenItemsHelper/SearchAjax?category=Personbil'

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0",
    "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "__RequestVerificationToken": "__5gL8glld19CRsUT8xTXmXEr-YzXF6_0VeJd_aLgoWHOqq2QU-D-UQSbB9Jjn60_N15L742nDFo_2W_DW-wOdoCJK9Zambqf7Qr0OwNgM81:6CZOtCzlWWD2SGiKILKI0rCfY5yHMPcVCCw6NBTpKtmp8HTIJpIkoPPa8NI2-7tPE-hMJT0MYDsmyh3aLDGpyf8IY_kPPoHT6CIQxu6Yfrs1",
    "IsJson": "true",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "Origin": "https://www.larmtjanst.se",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Referer": "https://www.larmtjanst.se/Efterlysta-objekt/Personbil/?s=True",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "TE": "Trailers"
}

request = Request(
    url=url,
    method='POST',
    dont_filter=True,
    headers=headers,
)

fetch(request)
```

As you can see you should set `__RequestVerificationToken` which can be found in the page body. Some of the other headers are necessary too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Michael but I tried that way and I get data that not rearranged. I should get table. Can you please check my code and let me know what's i'm doing wrong or its ok? https://pastebin.com/75Yjd9Y5

Comment: And the format I'm receiving https://pastebin.com/L5xjKbYM
is that ok or I should receive data inside the table. Please let me know. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're getting response in JSON format.
you can just json.loads(response.text) and then parse data.

Comment: Whole table is stored under "aaData" key

Comment: hello, can you please tell me about the `fetch()` function used at the end? where did you import the function from?

Comment: @hammi hi... `fetch()` is auto imported when you're using `scrapy shell`.
In this case code chunk mentioned above is intended to be executed in shell